# Can the Yahoo Finance Api retrieve Index data(specifically Nifty)?

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance, google-finance, yfinance

I wanted to retrieve Index spot data for indices, however can't find any solutions. Does the Yahoo Finance api provide the ability to do this, and if not are there any viable alternatives?

Comment: why not retrieve it directly from nifty website? if you look closely at https://www.nseindia.com/ you find they make calls to api at somepoint, using this you can get the data for desired index.. i know so because i did some scraping from this. feel free to contact if stuck.

Comment: And do post some code of what you did so far.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thanks for replying. Did you just directly scrape data from the nse website? And if so how did you manage to get shorter time frame data especially shorter time frame historical data. For example 1min data for the last couple days etc.

Comment: What do you mean by historical data in shorter time frame? As far as I can tell historical data are already there  and they are arranged in day interval, what I did is queried the data in regular interval (1min) and saved it to csv for creating my historical data as 1 min interval.

Comment: I’ll look into my GitHub, I think I have a script for latter in python.

Comment: Huh that makes sense. Yes any help will be appreciated as I've only recently started using python.

Comment: Did you researched about the api url of nse? Have you tried anything yet? Let’s continue in chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve data from the [following](https://python-yahoofinance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).
It is very well documented.